# What are *_Stub classes in JDK used for?

Tags: java, jndi, rmi, stub

In JDK, there are classes like *_Stub, for example:

[image]

But I didn't find the source of the class:

[image]

Where do those *_Stub classes come from? What are they used for?

Comment: @ProblemSlover No it isn't. It is a .class for which there is no source file. *Ergo* it wasn't generated by a decompiler. Don't post guesswork here.

Comment: This class, and other `_Stub` classes, was generated by the `rmic` program, about 23 years ago. Part of the JNDI/RMI infrastructure. Don't worry about it.

Comment: Thank you @user207421. Does that mean it's not included in the source but generated when the JDK is built?

Comment: Yes. `rmic` creates .class files. You can also make it generate .java files but there is no need. The stub class is what the client actually gets when it does a Registry lookup for example, implementing the remote interface the client needs,

Comment: @user207421, would you like to post an answer for this question? I can accept it. And thank you for providing the help :)